# Zero-width character does not render properly in close dialog

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-close, ios-app, custom-close-reasons

[image: StackOverflow App]

Besides the fact that this is an invalid close reason (I'll have to post another meta about that), the iOS app does not render these zero-width characters properly.

For reference, here's what the close reason looks like on the web:

[image: Web]

[Link to post.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44138540/2415822)

Comment: It's *completely* broken in the mod tools section.

Comment: HEY!  You're going to get me in trouble!

Comment: @Makoto Do you mean https://stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats ? Renders fine to me - http://i.imgur.com/h3K4Ibw.png. The main problem is that 5 questions were closed with a terrible reason.

Comment: @Rob:  I had seen an earlier version of that with nine usages.  Dunno what happened in the interim, but when I glanced at that page, it was definitely not rendering.

Comment: Then I tried typing `Robert'); DROP TABLE Students;--` and I accidentally the whole Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty much by design.  The label is being rendered with the user interface font, which renders `Zero Width Joiner U+200D` as an unknown character in most contexts.  I'm guessing it's a valid way to handle the character even if it's inconsistent with what WebKit does.

Blame either falls with Apple for not supporting it or Will for using the character without recognizing that inconsistencies in text rendering could expose his zero width secrets.  You could also look at the bright side, it's an accidental feature that helps identify users skirting the character requirement. :)

Comment: The sacred pact between SE and its power users is that the character requirement is only meant for those who are not smart enough to skirt around it. ;)

Comment: So, should SE disallow the Zero Width Joiner character in a CV reason?  Do I need to post a new meta feature request?